# Improve a magento setup on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rds

So i asked a question [here](https://serverfault.com/q/831788/396209) on how to improve connection to RDS from an EC2 instance. That has been successful so far.

I currently have a better setup that what i initially had and am looking for a way to improve it further. Current setup is as stated below.

`ELB` with autoscaling for multiple `EC2` instances running magento.

`EC2` instances running magento with `HHVM` with `varnish` and `NGINX`

`RDS` all `EC2` instance running magento are connected to this datastore with 3 read replica

`Elastic cache` redis session from all `EC2` instance are stored here.

`S3` all media and files are stored here, and mounted on all EC2 instance

After setting this up so far, i've been able to bring **TTFB** to 1.79s seconds from 7secs when i initially started, but its still running slightly slower than what's on our bare metal server with **TTFB** of 800ms.

How can i improve this architecture further?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of quick suggestions:

1. Setup CloudFront as a CDN (assuming you want to stay within the AWS infrastructure). This helps with the following:

   - Regional distribution of media assets in order to serve up assets geographically closer to your customer
   - Offload asset requests to a separate domain to ease [same-host browser restrictions](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top)
2. You mentioned that you use Redis for sessions, but I'm not seeing what you have for caching of backend/full-page/configuration etc. My recommendation would be to use a separate database of your ElastiCache instance for each cache type.
3. [Disable Magento modules that are no longer in use.](http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_declared_modules_tutorial/) This should speed up Magento by making sure only the needed modules are loaded on page-load.

With a proper setup of Magento and its infrastructure, it's easy to reach TTFB speeds of < 100ms. It's also possible that after all these optimizations, the bottleneck might be [the code itself](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-enable-the-magento-profiler.html) (custom functionality, poorly-written code, etc.).